# Android RecyclerView set start Position WITHOUT scrollTo

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

Scenario - I have created a custom Calendar using RecyclerView with a FlexboxLayoutManager.
The RecyclerView is provided with a CustomAdapter fed with a List of customDayData ranging from 2 years back (730 days) and 2 years in the Future (730) = 1461 items in the List.

I would like to show the Calendar at the current day - item 731. Given the large amount of Data, scrollToPosition(731) freezes the UI for 3-5 seconds (NOGO).

What would be the workaround to this issue. Many apps manage to do this instantly including Googles own Calendar Object. Is there an easy workaround or do I have to rethink the way I Load the Data?

Answer (score 0):

for large number of recycler item you should use pagination for better performance

Comment: Tnx for the reply,.It was always my understanding that the RecyclerView always behaved like Pagination only loading the visible Data +- a certain amount of Items to keep scrolling fluently. I can actually set data for 20 Years into the Adapter and Load the RecyclerView within 200-500ms. It is moving to a certain day within that Range of data I am having issues with

Answer (score 0):

I will try the following solution. Instead of loading single day data into the Adapter, I will Load Months and inflate the Days into the Month items. Hope this works because it will reduce the number of items by 30. ScrollToPosition should be relatively fast I guess